# HBS template with grunt-dr-svg-sprites

Tags: javascript, templates, gruntjs, handlebars.js

I'm using grunt to generate sprite SVG image (with PNG fallback) from separated SVG files and a (s)css file for the generated icons. For this process I'm using the [grunt-dr-svg-sprites](https://github.com/drdk/grunt-dr-svg-sprites/) and the template is using Handlebars syntax.

The idea of the structure what I would like to achieve is this:

```
@mixin prefix-filename {
  width: X;
  height: X;
  background-position: X X;
  @include background();
}
.
.
.
@mixin prefix-filename {
  width: X;
  height: X;
  background-position: X X;
  @include background();
}

@mixin background() {
  background-size: X X;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("sprite-with-its-path.png");

  .svg & {
    background-image: url("sprite-with-its-path.svg");
  }
}
```

But because I'm not really familiar with Handlebars template syntax the template what I've created is broken and doesn't work. It looks like this:

```
{{~#sizes~}}
{{~#items~}}

@mixin {{className}} {
  width: {{unit width ../../../config/cssUnit ../../../config/cssBaseFontSize}};
  height: {{unit height ../../../config/cssUnit ../../../config/cssBaseFontSize}};
  background-position: {{unit x ../../config/cssUnit ../../config/cssBaseFontSize -1}} {{unit y ../../config/cssUnit ../../config/cssBaseFontSize -1}};
  @include background();
}

{{/items~}}

@mixin background() {{prefix items ""}} {
  background-size: {{unit width ../../config/cssUnit ../../config/cssBaseFontSize}} {{unit height ../../config/cssUnit ../../config/cssBaseFontSize}};
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("{{url pngPath ../../cssPath}}");

{{~/sizes~}}

  .svg & {
    background-image: url("{{url ../svgPath ../cssPath}}");
  }
}
```

When I try to build the sprite, I get this error message:

> ```
> Building SVG sprites...
> Fatal error: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
> ```

But anyway the `{{className}}` at the mixin name also wrong if it's containing the "." (dot) at the beginning and also the `background()` mixin shouldn't contain any item-name too.

In the options I have defined the following attributes: `spriteElementPath`, `spritePath`, `cssPath`, `prefix`, `layout`, `cssUnit`, `template`

If I use the official template file, the sprite is generating properly, so the Grunt config is fine.

Could you please help me what the wrong is with my code and how can I achieve my original goal?

Thank you in advance!

**Update:**
I've just included the Grunt config's related part.

```
'svg-sprites': {
  'icons': {
    options: {
      spriteElementPath: svgProject + 'svg',
      spritePath: svgProject + 'output/icon-sprite.svg',
      cssPath: 'modules/_icon-sprite.scss',
      prefix: 'icon',
      layout: 'alt-diagonal',
      cssUnit: 'rem',
      template: svgProject + 'templates/custom_template.hbs'
    }
  }
},
```

**Update 2:**
Thanks to @hereandnow78 and @rasmusfl0e the help! They pointed out some important things and finally I could solved this issue. The main issue was the relative path in the background definitions. Here it is the final and working version of the template:

```
{{~#sizes~}}
{{~#items~}}
@mixin {{selector}} {
    width: {{unit width ../../config/cssUnit ../../config/cssBaseFontSize}};
    height: {{unit height ../../config/cssUnit ../../config/cssBaseFontSize}};
    background-position: {{unit x ../../config/cssUnit ../../config/cssBaseFontSize -1}} {{unit y ../../config/cssUnit ../../config/cssBaseFontSize -1}};
    @include background();
}
{{~/items~}}

@mixin background() {
    background-size: {{unit width ../config/cssUnit ../config/cssBaseFontSize}} {{unit height ../config/cssUnit ../config/cssBaseFontSize}};
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("{{url pngPath ../cssPath}}");

    .svg & {
        background-image: url("{{url ../svgPath ../cssPath}}");
    }
}
{{~/sizes~}}
```

Comment: your grunt config probably IS wrong, just because the error you have probably means some path-configs are wrong (i suspect you configured your destination as an array and not as a string).

Comment: But in this case why is it working perfectly with the official hbs template?

Comment: you are right, but maybe you just post the part of your config, just to make sure, should help to clarify your question

Comment: I did it just now. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have avoid the "." on classname you'll need to overwrite the default `options.selector` like this (in your config):

```
    selector: function (filename) {
        return "icon-" + filename;
    },
```

In your template there's a couple of things to change:

```
@mixin background() {{prefix items ""}} {
```

should probably just be:

```
@mixin background() {
```

And this bit:

```
  .svg & {
    background-image: url("{{url ../svgPath ../cssPath}}");
  }
}
```

probably needs to be inside the `sizes` brackets (just above `{{~/sizes~}}`).

I don't know what else might be wrong - but try it out and see how that gets you :D

Comment: The `selector` overwrite suggestion is perfect, thank you! In terms of the mixin heading definition thing I was just used that prefix section because in my previous versions of test caused error of the lack of it. And finally the last part of your suggestion was also right, I moved into the `sizes` section. But all of these still did not solved the original path issue unfortunately.The solution of that was the fixing the relative paths. :) I'll update my original question with the final, working solution.

Comment: Yeah - I should have remembered that changing scope of template code also affects nesting depth of paths - exactly like when moving stuff inside `sizes`. Glad you got it sorted! :)

Answer (score 0):

i see 2 possible issues in your hbs-template

1. missing tilde `~` on closing `items` (i suspect you customized the usage of `~`)

   wrong: {{/items~}}
   probably correct: {{~/items~}}
2. in your last block you are having a curly closing brace where the opening is missing:

   .svg & {
       background-image: url("{{url ../svgPath ../cssPath}}");
     }
   } <-- that one is probably obsolete

Comment: You are right, the tilde was missing, but it didn't cause any issue, I've tried it. In terms of the 2nd point that wasn't problem as well but the whole last part should be inside the `sizes` section like @rasmusfl0e suggested. Also the real problem was the path definition was wrong at first `cssPath`.